# I want to find the difference between two rows for a column field using fuse in ab initio

Tags: sql, database, etl, data-warehouse, ab-initio

I am new in Ab Initio and got stuck in this scenario.

```
TRADEID   TRADENAME    TRADETYPE    AMOUNT
1122      TCS          START        2400
1122      TCS          CLOSE        2800
```

I want to find the difference between the amounts ie. 2800 - 2400 using fuse component in ab initio.

Is it possible or i am going wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Fuse could only be used when you want to compare records of two different flows. But here it look like you are trying to take a difference out of a single input flow. How should your output look like?. If you want your output to be grouped on tradeid then you could sort on tradeid and then rollup on tradeid with a rollup tranform subtracting the amount. If you want a cumulative summary the you could sort on tradeid and then scan on tradeid as a key.